# How do I merge the following form with the following background?

Tags: html, css, forms, background

I was hoping someone could help me figure this out, i'm a newbie when it comes to coding.

I've made a form and a background in two seperate files. What i'm trying to achieve is:

1. Merge both files, wherein the form should be on the middle-right
   side of the screen and I want the background to stay like it is, it
   should keep changing both the images and background colour.
2. In the form, my scrollbar is going out of the div which has a
   border-radius, I want it to stay inside.
3. In the form, if you look at the dropdown menu, the bottom arrow
   isn't properly aligned, how can I move it towards it's left so it's visible properly.

I've tried a few solutions already, but either I mess up the background or the form's alignment changes. Please have a look at the following code for both the files and hopefully help a brother out.

I've also attached their Codepen links:
[(i) For the background:](https://codepen.io/sahajc/pen/zYqrrYJ)
[(ii) For the form:](https://codepen.io/sahajc/pen/rNexxaK)

**CODE FOR THE BACKGROUND:**

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="SurveyForm.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" 
      integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Lego Technic Survey Form</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="images" id="one">
           <img class="cars" id="lambo" src="Lamborgini.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="images" id="two">
           <img class="cars" id="bugatti" src="Bugatti.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="images" id="three">
           <img class="cars" id="porsche" src="Porsche.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="images" id="four">
           <img class="cars" id="dodge" src="Dodge.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="images" id="five">
           <img class="cars" id="chevrolet" src="Chevrolet.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <script>
             var myIndex = 0;
             carousel();

             function carousel() {
             var i;
             var x = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
             for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                 x[i].style.display = "none";  
             }
             myIndex++;
             if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
             x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
             setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
             }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

#one {
    background-color: #9dde75;
}

#two {
    background-color: #66b1e0;
}

#three {
    background-color: #e65643;
}

#four {
    background-color: #3e3c42;
}

#five {
    background-color: #ee8952d7;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;      
}

.cars {
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#porsche {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#chevrolet {
    margin-top: 180px;
}
```

**CODE FOR THE FORM:**

**HTML:**

```
<body>

    <div class="neumorphic-form">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="legologo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1 id="title">Lego Technic Survey Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us be more creative</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="fields">
            <form id="survey-form" action="">
                    <div class="username">
                        <label for="name" id="name-label" hidden>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="email">
                        <label for="email" id="email-label" hidden>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="number">
                        <label for="tel" id="number-label" hidden>Contact Number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter your contact number"><br>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="favourite">
                        <p>Which is your favorite Lego Technic Building Set?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdownoptions">
                        <select name="buildingset" id="dropdown">
                            <option disabled selected value>Select any one set</option>
                            <option value="Lamborgini Sián FKP 37">Lamborgini Sián FKP 37</option>
                            <option value="Bugatti Chiron">Bugatti Chiron</option>
                            <option value="Porsche 911 RSR">Porsche 911 RSR</option>
                            <option value="Dodge Charger">Dodge Charger</option>
                            <option value="Chevrolet Corvette ZR1">Chevrolet Corvette ZR1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                
                    <p>Would you recommend to buy Lego Technic to a friend?</p>
                    <div class="neumorph">
                        <input type="radio" id="definitely" class="radiocheck" name="a" checked>
                        <label for="definitely">Definitely</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="maybe" class="radiocheck" name="a">
                        <label for="maybe">Maybe</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="notsure" class="radiocheck" name="a">
                        <label for="notsure">Not Sure</label>
                    
                    <p>Which Lego Technic sets would you like to see in the future?</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="ferrarilaferrari" name="b" value="ferrarilaferrari" checked>
                        <label for="ferrarilaferrari"> Ferrari LaFerrari</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="zenvots1gt" name="b" value="Zenvots1gt">
                        <label for="Zenvots1gt"> Zenvo TS1 GT</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="koenigseggone" name="b" value="koenigseggone">
                        <label for="koenigseggone"> Koenigsegg One</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="mercedesamgone" name="b" value="mercedesamgone">
                        <label for="mercedesamgone"> Mercedes-AMG One</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="paganihuayrabc" name="b" value="paganihuayrabc">
                        <label for="paganihuayrabc"> Pagani Huayra BC</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="astonmartinvalkyrie" name="b" value="astonmartinvalkyrie">
                        <label for="astonmartinvalkyrie"> Aston Martin Valkyrie</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="mercedesbenzmaybachexelero" name="b" value="mercedesbenzmaybachexelero">
                        <label for="mercedesbenzmaybachexelero"> Mercedes Benz Maybach Exelero</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="rollsroycesweptail" name="b" value="rollsroycesweptail">
                        <label for="rollsroycesweptail"> Rolls Royce Sweptail</label> <br><br>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="comments">
                        <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" placeholder="Enter your comments or suggestions here..." rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   color: #555;
   background: #ecf0f3;
}

.neumorphic-form {
   overflow: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width: 430px;
   height: 700px;
   padding: 60px 35px 35px 35px;
   border-radius: 40px;
   background: #ecf0f3;
   box-shadow: 13px 13px 20px #cbced1,
               -13px -13px 20px #ffffff;
}

.logo {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #5f5f5f,
               0px 0px 0px 5px #ecf0f3,
            8px 8px 15px #a7aaaf,
            -8px -8px 15px #ffffff;
}

img {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#title {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 24px;
   padding-top: 18px;
   letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

#description {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fields {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.fields input, textarea, #dropdown {
   border: none;
   outline:none;
   background: none;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #555;
   padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}

.username, .email, .number, .comments, #dropdown {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   box-shadow: inset 8px 8px 8px #cbced1,
               inset -8px -8px 8px #ffffff;
}

#name, #email, #number, #textarea, #dropdown {
   width: 100%;
}   

textarea {
   resize: none;
}

button {
   outline: none;
   border:none;
   cursor: pointer;
   width:100%;
   height: 60px;
   border-radius: 30px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   color:#fff;
   text-align: center;
   background: #ed462f;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #b1b1b1,
               -3px -3px 8px #ffffff;
   transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
   background:#992c1d;
}
  
button:active {
   background:#ed462f;
}
 
label, input {
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-weight: 400;
}

p {
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   text-align: justify;
}

#dropdown {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.neumorph > input[type=radio].radiocheck,
.neumorph > input[type=checkbox].radiocheck {
   position: relative;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   margin: 10px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               -5px -5px 10px rgba(255,255,255,1),
               inset 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               inset 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
   outline: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.neumorph > input[type=radio].radiocheck:checked,
.neumorph > input[type=checkbox].radiocheck:checked {
   background-color: #ed462f;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,1),
               inset 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               inset -5px -5px 10px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.neumorph > input[type=radio].radiocheck {
   border-radius: 50%;
}

.neumorph > input[type=checkbox].radiocheck {
   border-radius: 20%;
}

.neumorph > input[type=radio].radiocheck::before,
.neumorph > input[type=checkbox].radiocheck::before {
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
   font-weight: 900;
   color: #eee;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.neumorph > input[type=radio].radiocheck::before {
   content: "\f111";
   font-size: 10px;
}

.neumorph > input[type=checkbox].radiocheck::before {
   content: "\f00c";
   font-size: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.555);
   border: 4px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 8px;
   background-clip: padding-box;
}
  
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 16px;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a container for both components, merged them and fixed css.
The key was to put the images slideshow in `position: fixed;` and center the form.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

.images-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.images {
    height: 100%;
}

#one {
    background-color: #9dde75;
}

#two {
    background-color: #66b1e0;
}

#three {
    background-color: #e65643;
}

#four {
    background-color: #3e3c42;
}

#five {
    background-color: #ee8952d7;
}

#one,
#two,
#three,
#four,
#five {
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cars {
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#porsche {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#chevrolet {
    margin-top: 180px;
}

.neumorphic-form {
    z-index: 2 overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 430px;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 60px 35px 35px 35px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #ecf0f3;
    box-shadow: 13px 13px 20px #cbced1, -13px -13px 20px #ffffff;
}

.logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #5f5f5f, 0px 0px 0px 5px #ecf0f3, 8px 8px 15px #a7aaaf, -8px -8px 15px #ffffff;
}

.neumorphic-form img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

#description {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fields {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.fields input,
textarea,
#dropdown {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}

.username,
.email,
.number,
.comments,
#dropdown {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 8px 8px 8px #cbced1, inset -8px -8px 8px #ffffff;
}

#name,
#email,
#number,
#textarea,
#dropdown {
    width: 100%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

button {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ed462f;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #b1b1b1, -3px -3px 8px #ffffff;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
    background: #992c1d;
}

button:active {
    background: #ed462f;
}

label,
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 400;
}

p {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#dropdown {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.neumorph>input[type=radio].radiocheck,
.neumorph>input[type=checkbox].radiocheck {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), -5px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), inset 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.neumorph>input[type=radio].radiocheck:checked,
.neumorph>input[type=checkbox].radiocheck:checked {
    background-color: #ed462f;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), inset -5px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.neumorph>input[type=radio].radiocheck {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.neumorph>input[type=checkbox].radiocheck {
    border-radius: 20%;
}

.neumorph>input[type=radio].radiocheck::before,
.neumorph>input[type=checkbox].radiocheck::before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.neumorph>input[type=radio].radiocheck::before {
    content: "\f111";
    font-size: 10px;
}

.neumorph>input[type=checkbox].radiocheck::before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-size: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.555);
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="neumorphic-form">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G23dM93h/legologo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1 id="title">Lego Technic Survey Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us be more creative</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="fields">
            <form id="survey-form" action="">
                    <div class="username">
                        <label for="name" id="name-label" hidden>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="email">
                        <label for="email" id="email-label" hidden>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="number">
                        <label for="tel" id="number-label" hidden>Contact Number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter your contact number"><br>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="favourite">
                        <p>Which is your favorite Lego Technic Building Set?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdownoptions">
                        <select name="buildingset" id="dropdown">
                            <option disabled selected value>Select any one set</option>
                            <option value="Lamborgini Sián FKP 37">Lamborgini Sián FKP 37</option>
                            <option value="Bugatti Chiron">Bugatti Chiron</option>
                            <option value="Porsche 911 RSR">Porsche 911 RSR</option>
                            <option value="Dodge Charger">Dodge Charger</option>
                            <option value="Chevrolet Corvette ZR1">Chevrolet Corvette ZR1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                
                    <p>Would you recommend to buy Lego Technic to a friend?</p>
                    <div class="neumorph">
                        <input type="radio" id="definitely" class="radiocheck" name="a" checked>
                        <label for="definitely">Definitely</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="maybe" class="radiocheck" name="a">
                        <label for="maybe">Maybe</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="notsure" class="radiocheck" name="a">
                        <label for="notsure">Not Sure</label>
                    
                    <p>Which Lego Technic sets would you like to see in the future?</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="ferrarilaferrari" name="b" value="ferrarilaferrari" checked>
                        <label for="ferrarilaferrari"> Ferrari LaFerrari</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="zenvots1gt" name="b" value="Zenvots1gt">
                        <label for="Zenvots1gt"> Zenvo TS1 GT</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="koenigseggone" name="b" value="koenigseggone">
                        <label for="koenigseggone"> Koenigsegg One</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="mercedesamgone" name="b" value="mercedesamgone">
                        <label for="mercedesamgone"> Mercedes-AMG One</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="paganihuayrabc" name="b" value="paganihuayrabc">
                        <label for="paganihuayrabc"> Pagani Huayra BC</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="astonmartinvalkyrie" name="b" value="astonmartinvalkyrie">
                        <label for="astonmartinvalkyrie"> Aston Martin Valkyrie</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="mercedesbenzmaybachexelero" name="b" value="mercedesbenzmaybachexelero">
                        <label for="mercedesbenzmaybachexelero"> Mercedes Benz Maybach Exelero</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck" id="rollsroycesweptail" name="b" value="rollsroycesweptail">
                        <label for="rollsroycesweptail"> Rolls Royce Sweptail</label> <br><br>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="comments">
                        <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" placeholder="Enter your comments or suggestions here..." rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="images-container">
<div class="images" id="one">
                <img class="cars" id="lambo" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Xqp3bhyR/Lamborgini.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="images" id="two">
                <img class="cars" id="bugatti" src="https://i.postimg.cc/KvCcZZfJ/Bugatti.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="images" id="three">
                <img class="cars" id="porsche" src="https://i.postimg.cc/kGzCXcQB/Porsche.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="images" id="four">
                <img class="cars" id="dodge" src="https://i.postimg.cc/3RL7z7Wj/Dodge.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="images" id="five">
                <img class="cars" id="chevrolet" src="https://i.postimg.cc/1zrycDQj/Chevrolet.png" alt="">
            </div>
</div>
<script>
                var myIndex = 0;
                carousel();

                function carousel() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";  
                }
                myIndex++;
                if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
                x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
                }
        </script>
```